# iOS Local Notification Trigger Handling

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am currently making an app which counts the steps walked and check with goal and release local notification if met.
I have set up the local notification but I want that to trigger just once at that moment. I got this working through dispatch_once_t:

```
if stepsData >= stepsGoalData {
            let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
            localNotification.fireDate = NSDate()
            localNotification.alertBody = "Acheived"
            localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    }
```

But in case if the user increases the stepsGoalData, currently the code doesn't trigger the notification. Can someone please provide me with an idea to handle this case. Thank you!

Comment: why did you add the `dispatch_once`? what problem did it solve exactly?

Comment: Currently, I noticed comparing exactly two values which in which one has pedometer data was impossible. So I had to use >= to compare the data and with that if I don't add dispatch_once it was continuously generating notifications and by using this it just generated it once which was my aim. I think there might be a better way to handle this as well but on searching I couldn't find one :(

Comment: you need to revert that last edit to your question as it now doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you should really just change the check for wether to notify or not so that it considers not just the count but also a flag to indicate if the notification has been made. This can be a var defined beside your `stepsGoalData` as a simple `Bool`.

Now, your check would be:

```
if stepsData >= stepsGoalData && !hasNotified {
    hasNotified = true
    ...
```

And when you set the `stepsGoalData` to a new target value you also set `hasNotified = false`.

Comment: for sure, otherwise it won't work again until the app is removed from memory

Comment: I have updated my code with what you have recommended, if I got that right and understood what you tried to explain here I am getting continuous notifications now.

Comment: Just to let you know that the method which has this code is called continuously through a selector method.

Comment: `hasNotified` should be an instance variable like `stepsGoalData`, not a local func variable...

Comment: did you debug? is the flag set to `false` initially? you should always get inside once, set the flag and notify, then not get in

Comment: My bad! Yes it goes in but there is no change in functionality overall. If the notification is triggered and after that user changes his goal and if that goal is met there is no notification for that scenario.

For example:

Initial goal = 2000 -> condition met -> notified
After that, goal increased by 100 there is no notification once that 2100 is met. I want that to happen.

Comment: and you're resetting the flag when you update the goal? i realise my answer wasn't 100% clear in regard to this point so i've edited a little

Comment: Thank you! Got the idea but setting the notified as a instance variable didn't worked, I think I know the reason behind that now. So, I just saved the bool value in nsuserdefault and then compared!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108365/discussion-between-alakh-and-wain).